# codeigniter where in clause show result by or

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

i have some problem when use 'where in' in codeigniter, i want modify the clause not using and but using or.

this is the code:

```
$this->db->where_in('id','1,2,3');
```

it works like this:

```
$this->db->where('id',1);
$this->db->where('id',2);
$this->db->where('id',3);
```

but i want the result like this:

```
$this->db->where('id',1);
$this->db->or_where('id',2);
$this->db->or_where('id',3);
```

but it still use where in not where. thank you

Comment: add all the codes you are using.

Comment: Please post what result you want to get. and what result are you getting. also post the sample table you are having.

Answer (score 3):

Your `where_in()` usage is wrong. You must declare the values you wanted to compare in an `array` like this:

```
$ids = array('1', '2', '3');
$this->db->where_in('id', $ids);
//Produces: WHERE id IN ('1', '2', '3')
```

or like this:

```
$this->db->where_in('id', array('1', '2', '3'));
//Produces: WHERE id IN ('1', '2', '3')
```

Answer (score 1):

What about using this:

```
$id = array('1', '2', '3');
$this->db->or_where_in('id', $ids);
```

**UPDATE:**

```
$this->db->select()->from('tbl')
   ->group_start()
     ->where('id', 1)
     ->or_group_start()
       ->where('id', 2)
       ->where('id', 3)
     ->group_end()
   ->group_end();
```

Comment: it work, but when only one condition and the condition not match with thedata, the result still showing

Answer (score 0):

Please check the syntax of where_in

```
$this->db->where_in()
```

Generates a `WHERE field IN (item, item)` SQL query joined with AND if appropriate

```
$ids = array(1, 2, 3);
$this->db->where_in('id', $ids);


$this->db->or_where_in()
```

Generates a `WHERE field IN (‘item’, ‘item’)` SQL query joined with OR if appropriate

```
$ids = array('1', '2', '3');
$this->db->or_where_in('id', $ids);


$this->db->where_not_in()
```

Generates a `WHERE field NOT IN (‘item’, ‘item’)` SQL query joined with AND if appropriate

```
$ids = array('1', '2', '3');
$this->db->where_not_in('id', $ids);


$this->db->or_where_not_in()
```

Generates a `WHERE field NOT IN (‘item’, ‘item’)` SQL query joined with OR if appropriate

```
$ids = array('1', '2', '3');
$this->db->or_where_not_in('id', $ids);
```

For more information please refer official documentation [https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html](http://Codeigniter%20Documentation)